# Setting up in-video ads with JWplayer wordpress plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I've tried and tried to make this code work but with no success.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    jwplayer().onReady(function() {
var currentItem = jwplayer().getPlaylistItem().file + ‘?wmode=transparent’;
jwplayer().load({file: currentItem});
var params = {
ignore_swfobject: '1'
});
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
var exoOpts = {
  cat: '118',
  login: 'thelogin',
  idzone_300x250: '720635',
  idzone_468x60: '720635',
  idsite: '243347',
  pause: {},
  postroll: {},
  show_thumb: '1'
};
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ads.exoclick.com/invideo.js"></script>
```

The ad appears when the video is on pause. It just makes the video disappear and there is no way back to the video other than reloading the page.
I tried to put this code before the video in the post page to set wmode to transparent and the -

```
var params = {
ignore_swfobject: '1'
};
```

As specified by the ad network.
I'm pretty new to this.. Did I messed up something? Did added it in the wrong place? I put it in single-video.php. I use Wordpress self hosted. Can you help me with this?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Did you find the solution for this?